# Full screen calendar Vue+Laravel - how to approach?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2

I am pretty new to Vue.js, but kind of know my way around it.

I have to make a SPA with a huge calendar where people select their dates and see available hours at those days and then do stuff with those dates.

The calendar should be the main star of the page - a huge one with the ability to change the months ahead to infinity and beyond and I'm thinking how should I approach it.

Should I search for already done Vue components? Or should I write it in Laravel/Blade and then just power it up with Vue?

Or should I just try and write it in Vue from the ground up?

What's the best practice in this case scenario?

Comment: See if any of these fit your bill: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#calendar

Answer (score 1):

First, Make a Model in the laravel. For example, Date, Time, To do list ... etc.
Second, Serialize model to the json.
Third, Make a Calendar with that json file.